# AWS console see what action has been done by which user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On the AWS console, is there any history of users actions? I would like to see which of ours users has last modified a property of a S3 bucket for example

Answer (score 2):

For this you can do few things.

- Setup [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) to audit user actions to AWS S3
- Enable logging for the S3 bucket and store the logs either in a bucket in the same account of in a different account (Better if you need more security).
- Enable versioning on S3 buckets, so past versions remains and allows to revert the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to collect all user actions in AWS is using CloudTrail. Using CloudTrail you can also create trails that includes S3 object-level operation events.